# How to use Mono to compile C# code for use by a Mac

Tags: c#, mono

I want to develop a C# (WPF or Winforms) application to use on a Mac. I am running Windows. This question has two parts. Would Vine be able to run a WPF or Winforms application and would Mono let me compile an .cs program file to run on Mac? Please note: My program is reliant on the ability to edit the Mac's files. I don't want the Mac user to need to install Mono. If there is no way to use Mono, could someone suggest an alternative way to code for a Mac on a Windows machine (preferably C#, if not C# maybe java)? I am aware that WPF doesn't work with Mono.

I have installed Mono and used the `csc hello.cs` command from https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/. This command created a working `.exe` file for Windows. I can't figure out if Mono will let me compile for a Mac. My problem may be that I don't understand how Mono works/what it is used for. If that is the case, please explain how I could use Mono.

This is the hello.cs program (not sure if it helps). Please not: I know it is not a WPF or Winforms app; I just want to test if I can get a console app to run on Mac:

```
using System;

namespace Dela.Mono.Examples
{
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World. Hit Enter to exit program.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to see a Mac version of .exe. The program does not run on Mac.

Comment: Any reason not to just use Visual Studio for MacOS and create a .net Core app?

Comment: I am pretty sure Mono still does not support WPF and is not planned to get it anytime soon. The closest thing would be UWP in .NET Core, I guess. In a nutshell, it is "WPF with supprort for Apps" However it is worth pointing out that .NET Core 3 will get WindowsForms support, including a mapping to Linux and Mac Internal drawing systems - I think.

Comment: @Hursey I run windows but I want to make an app for Mac. I don't think I can run Visual Studio for MacOS on a windows machine.

Comment: @eagertuna0: Normally I would say "run a VM", but this is MacOS. "Thou shall not run my code on other hardware." No idea if they finally slacked off with that a bit with the latest version or still check for tha Mac-only chip.

Comment: Well then, you can create a .NetCore app on your windows development machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos

Comment: @Christopher I updated my question to note that I am willing to migrate my app to WinForms. Also does UWP work on Mac? To clarify: The question is more about if I can use Mono or another program to make a Mac version of an .exe on windows (I am fine using something other than WPF or WinForms if impossible).

Comment: @eagertuna0: .NET Core works on MacOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites | And UWP is part of .NET Core, as much as WPF is part of the .NET Framework. As long as the target Framework is right, it is someone elses problem.

Comment: Oh, even better: .NET 3.0 will also have Native WPF support: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/ Projects targetted at .NET Framework WinForms need a conversion tool to have them fit .NET Core 3.0 WinForms. No idea if that also applies to WPF migration.

Comment: Though it is not 100% duplicate to the linked thread, asking for WPF/WinForms on macOS is an old question for more than a decade. You might get some ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score -2):

You can just run your exe file inside mac passing it to the mono runtime.

Comment: This is completely wrong, as WinForms or WPF apps won't run on Mono on macOS.